# How to detect when a FullScreen event happens,on f11 key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to detect when a FullScreen event happens,on f11 key press. if it happens that means,the screen is in FullScreen mode then show an alert.Not using keycode comparison.Plz give me a different way to do this.

```
// mozilla proposal
element.requestFullScreen();
document.cancelFullScreen(); 

// Webkit (works in Safari and Chrome Canary)
element.webkitRequestFullScreen(); 
document.webkitCancelFullScreen(); 

// Firefox (works in nightly)
element.mozRequestFullScreen();
document.mozCancelFullScreen(); 

// W3C Proposal
element.requestFullscreen();
document.exitFullscreen();
```

or

```
element.addEventListener('fullscreeneventchange', function(e) {
    if (document.fullScreen) {
       /* make it look good for fullscreen */
    } else {
       /* return to the normal state in page */
    }
}, true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.onresize = function (event) {
    var maxHeight = window.screen.height,
        maxWidth = window.screen.width,
        curHeight = window.innerHeight,
        curWidth = window.innerWidth;

    if (maxWidth == curWidth && maxHeight == curHeight) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also try window.screen.availWidth & window.screen.availHeight (note that these might not actually be the screen resolution but have allowances for the width of the menubars/browser window dimensions, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, buddy, actually, I need this for VueJs.

Comment: `window.innerHeight` is decreased when I open the developer toolbar at the bottom. :(

Comment: By the way, this doesn't work if dev tools are open.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for fullscreen on **F11** keypress then try the following fiddle:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/yXVr6/) / [Fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/yXVr6/show/)

```
function checkWH(){
    if((window.outerWidth-screen.width) ==0 && (window.outerHeight-screen.height) ==0 )
    {
        alert('fullscreen');
    }
}

$(window).keypress(function(event){
    var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if(code == 122){
        setTimeout(function(){checkWH();},1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: keypress does not catch the event sent by the F11 key in Chrome but it works with keydown or keyup.

Comment: this whole full screen thing is ridiculous. i can't believe how much hacking i have to do for something so simple. seriously, get your shit together Chrome. "because security" is not an excuse for everything. Developer should be able to tell, consistently, if a user enters full screen, wether by f11 or the API. This shit is frustrating.

Comment: if I'm not in F11 - fullscreen mode, but the condition is still true just because the browser fills the whole screen.