# How to check if the browser is in fullscreen mode?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, fullscreen

I know about the new Fullscreen API but I can't find anywhere a way to check if the browser at this time is in fullscreen mode. I'm specifically interested about Chrome. Is it even possible?

I'm looking for something like this

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (FULLSCREEN) {
        console.log('We are in full screen mode!')
    } else {
        console.log('Normal mode')
    }
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if browser is in fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863351/checking-if-browser-is-in-fullscreen)

Answer (score 6):

If the document is in fullscreen mode, `document.fullscreenElement` will return the element that triggered the mode. When not in fullscreen, it returns `null`. In some browsers you may need to use the prefixed version, `document.webkitFullscreenElement`.

[MDN: fullscreenElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/fullscreenElement)

Comment: Ah yes, didn't think of that.

Comment: If fullscreen is activated with F11 in Chrome, this will not work. You can find a workaround for that here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662128/how-to-detect-when-a-fullscreen-event-happens-on-f11-key-press

Answer (score 0):

As per the Fullscreen API mdn doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API
Its not supported in chrome.

Comment: Is there any other way to detect if Chrome is in full screen?

Comment: I think this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863351/checking-if-browser-is-in-fullscreen

Answer (score -2):

Why not use the simple method of pressing F11. In this way, you can see if Chrome is viewed in full-screen or normal mode. Maybe you can find some advice reding this article https://rocketfiles.com/articles/how-to-exit-full-screen-chrome. I have not used the API you request but will try. Maybe will write to you more information later that I can learn from my side.